# Hardcore javascript module scope

Tags: javascript, scope

The problem : I want to iterate over my list of functions, and modify them in place, using code like:

```
for(var funcProperty in scope) {
    scope['_'+funcProperty] = scope[funcProperty];
    scope[funcProperty] = wrapFunctionInTryCatchBlock(scope['_'+funcProperty]);
}
```

I want to do this without explicitly having to go through all my functions, and add them to some object, thereby creating the required scope. I don't want to do that because then all the functions, which call each other, will have to have their names modified and lengthened to become:

`funcName` becomes `scopeObject.funcName` : **annoying.**

I could do this quite easily if my functions were in the global object, i.e, `Window`, however I don't want to pollute the global namespace, so I have put them in a module, like so:

```
var MyModule = (function() {
    function privateFunc1(...) {...} 
    function privateFunc2(...) {...}

    var public_api = {
        coolName : privateFunc1
    };
    return public_api;
}());
```

However, I can see and find no way to access the scope object that exists in the immediately executed function call the return value of which is assigned to MyModule.

I tried doing this, from within MyModule:

`console.log(this)`

To see if we did have access to the scope, somehow, yet, of course, it turned out that this referred to Window.

My question is really: **What is** the scope object that the methods in MyModule private scope are assigned to, since it is not the global object, and it does exist, since all the functions have implicit access to it. Is there any way I as a JavaScript programmer can **explicitly access** the scope object and enumerate its properties or is that FORBIDDEN?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to rush to accept this as the answer, but I have found one *possible* solution that I am happy with.

Definition of "happy with" in this case is : minimal extra work, almost no changes to existing code.

**The solution**

We modify the module code like so:

```
// $ = wrapFunctionInTryCatchBlock
function $(fun) {
return function() { 
   try {
        return fun.apply(this,arguments);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("Error",err,err.stack);
    }
};
}

var MyModule = (function() {
    var privateFun1 = $(privateFun1(...){...});
    var privateFun2 = $(privateFun2(...){...});

    var public_api = {
        coolName : privateFun1
    };
    return public_api;
}());
```

**Why this works**

We get the desired code modification (function wrapping), essentially in place since the variables assigned to function expressions have exactly the same scope as the original named functions themselves.

**A VIM regex to help**

I also created a VIM regex to help with this, at least the assignment line anyway:

`s/function \(\w\+\)\(.\+\)$/var \1 = $(function \1\2/g`